# how to automatically escape the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, string-literals

I have a path string like `c:\user\test\test.jpg`, how can I make it `c:\\user\\test\\test.jpg`?

Comment: you can not assign a string like string s="c:\user\test\test.jpg"; It will give compilation error, string can take only "\\" instead of "\", But string literal "\\" always treated same as "\".

Comment: @Asif, that is not correct.  See my answer.

Comment: @AsifQadri, not only one can use the verbatim string syntax to define a string (the at sign), but also one could pass such a string into the arguments of a 'main' function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string s = s.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
string path = @"c:\user\test\test.jpg";
```

Comment: how to do opposite of this? and when there are random no of \\ in the path for e.g. how can i make this path C:\\abcdef\\\\smstr\\iretrieval\\20_newsgroups\\20_newsgroups\\alt.atheism\\ as C:\abcdef\smstr\iretrieval\20_newsgroups\20_newsgroups\alt.atheism\?

Answer (score 5):

you would only require escaping if you are using string literal in the code. why would you require automatic escaping anyways. you can use @ before the literal that requires no escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try something like: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape, of course that will do all escaped characters.