# asp.net replace special character '\'

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

I have a string ,it gives a source path from a png image ex:

```
C:\pictures\picture1.png
```

But I will replace the '\' character to '\ \' (two \ character )with this line :

my data is `C:\pictures\picture1.png`

```
 public string rep(string data) 
        {
            data.Replace('\','\\');
            return data;
        }
```

when I rite data.Replace('\','\') the next characters after '\' comes to description line what can I do I must use the file source so :

```
C:\\pictures\\picture1.png
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543686/how-to-automatically-escape-the-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
data = data.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Backslashes must be doubled in strings.

(Or use "raw strings":

```
data = data.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your:

```
data.Replace("\","\\\\");
```

Line is not doing anything since Replace returns a **new** string with the result. Perhaps what you intend to do is `data=data.Replace()...`?

Comment: I will use this line in Image Url